# Mysql - changing an alias name modify the result

Tags: mysql, casting, alias

I found this beahviour quite strange in Mysql 5.5.29

Those 2 requests are supposed to do the same thing, but I don't have the same result, wether the only thing that changes is the alias name :

---

```
 select count(*), CAST(pcc1 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as pcc1 from inverters.daily_data group by pcc1
```

result sample : 
'2', '1000.08'
'1', '1000.37'
'1', '1000.62'
'1', '1000.83'
'1', '10003.92'
'1', '10005.18'

---

```
 select count(*), CAST(pcc1 as DECIMAL(10,2)) as r_pcc1 from inverters.daily_data group by r_pcc1
```

result sample : 
'1', '198.26'
'1', '247.52'
'1', '258.64'
'1', '266.25'
'1', '274.40'

this second sample is absolutely wrong, there is no value corresponding in the whole table
Does anybody have an explanation ?

---

some precisions : I have to modifiy a database in wich values were stored as varchar, but I want to analyse the incoherent values. I know that CAST is not appropriated because it stores the exact value, but for the moment I just want to watch at the values repartition

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that MySQL is defaulting to use the non aliased column name that matches the GROUP BY column specified, and if one isn't found it uses alias names instead. In your first example it this groups by the non cast value, while in the 2nd it can't find a non aliased column name called r_pcc1 so it instead uses the aliased column r_pcc1

Possible explanation in this rejected MySQL bug report:-

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=188